# normal php DELETE string gets error

Tags: php, mysql

I am using a query to delete a row... The quotes seems fine..But am getting error..
i tried the following two ways, but it is not working..

```
          $sch=mysql_query("DELETE FROM schedule WHERE
    membername='$value' AND trainername='$_SESSION['username']'") or die(mysql_error());

           $sch= mysql_query("DELETE FROM schedule 
                       WHERE membername=$value 
                        AND trainername=$_SESSION['username']");
```

Any suggestion?? Thank You..

Comment: Please, read up on [proper SQL escaping](http://bobby-tables.com/) before you get in trouble.

Comment: You **absolutely** need to be escaping _every single_ value that goes to your database. Period. End of story. Whether it comes from a session or a constant defined two lines above your query. _Always_ escape. And you probably should move away from MySQL to PDO/MySQLi - since `mysql_*` functions are deprecated

Comment: mysql_query()? are you aware of the non-depreciated method mysqli_query()?

Comment: PDO is better than `mysqli`, and better still is using [a proper framework](http://www.phpframeworks.com/top-10-php-frameworks/) instead of smashing around with raw SQL.

Comment: Your `delete` query is perfect, can you tell me which error you are getting?

Comment: The only one that luckily skipped the deprecation (which is not the question) and escaping (which is the rule of thumb, in fact, but may not be the problem) is @SumitBijvani. Telling him how rude is to still use `mysql` looks like _"Why do you use a pan for making chips? You should use a deep-fryer"_. Maybe this project is years old, maybe the server will never get newer PHP versions. The tool he is using may be just fine for the case. The solution could simply go through `echoing` the query and printing `mysql_error()` to see what happened.

Answer (score 0):

You need to wrap the array variable in the string with curly braces.

```
$test = "this is a test {$_SESSION['string']}";
```

Comment: You need to wrap this in `mysql_real_escape_string` or it's just plain reckless.

Comment: @tadman that doesn't imply a downvote, since using `mysql_` in the first place is **bad**.

Comment: yes, use pdo/mysqli or at least escape the string...etc. all that junk. That is why I didn't use sql in my example. This is still a problem they have with their code.

Comment: Fair enough. It's still worth mentioning that this wouldn't even be a problem if SQL placeholders were used.

Answer (score 0):

You can't use quoted array keys in a PHP double-quoted string. It should be

```
  ... AND trainername=$_SESSION[username] ...
or
  ... AND trainername={$_SESSION['username']} ...
```

You've also forgotten to **QUOTE** those presumed-strings you're inserting into the query

```
... AND trainername='...'
                    ^---^--
```

Comment: Don't advocate the first solution...I know it's valid when it's inside a string - but people will have a tendency to use the same notation outside of a string as well. Sadly for the future of PHP - it works...but it's bad practice.

Comment: Neither of these is escaped correctly and won't work. `AND trainername=bob` is not valid SQL.

Comment: Both quoting *and* escaping are required for this to be valid.

Comment: It's not valid. If username is `O'Malley` then it will not work.

Comment: Plus, escaping without quoting may **still** lead to SQL injection anyway. `trainername=0 OR 1=1` (see [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5741264/616225))